# Plot f(x,g(x)) where u(x,g(x))=0 can not be solved explicitly

Tags: plotting, implicit

Suppose $u(x,g(x))=0$ can not be solved explicitly for $g(x)$. I need to plot $f(x,g(x))$. How can this be done?

An example: $\frac{1}{\log y}=y-x$ for $x\ge 1$ has a solution for $y$, but can not be solved explicitly. And I would like to plot $y^2+x$ for $x\in[1,4]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the constraint `x -> y - 1/Log[y]` for x!

```
 ParametricPlot[ {x, x + y^2} /. x -> y - 1/Log[y] , {y, 1, 10},AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{1, 4}, {0, 20}},AxesLabel -> {x, x + y^2}]
```

[image]

**addenum**
If you cannot solve the constraint for x you can do it numerically:

ContourPlot shows you two possible solutions y[x]

```
ContourPlot[1/Log[y] == y - x, {x, 1, 4}, {y, 0, 5}]
```

[image]

numerical solution of the constraint

```
sol[x_] := y /. NSolve[ {x ==  y - 1/Log[y], 5 > y > 0}, y]
Plot[ Evaluate[x + sol[x] ^2] , {x, 1, 4}, AxesLabel -> {x, x + y^2},PlotLabel -> "constraint x\[Equal]  y-1/Log[y]" ]
```

[image]

Comment: A nice solution! But what if $x$ cannot be solved explicitly from the constraint either?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to numerically minimize the difference between the LHS and the RHS at each point, and then plot the location of the resulting minima. Here f[x] is the y value that fulfills the equation, and then the desired function is to plot x+y^2, which is x+f[x]^2. It looks like a straight line because f[x] is pretty small.

```
f[x_] := NMinimize[Abs[1/Log[y] - (y - x)], y][[2, 1, 2]] // Quiet
Plot[x + f[x]^2, {x, 1, 4}]
```

For example, at x = 1, the min occurs at {y -> 0.2592}, which means that x + y^2 is 1 + 0.259246^2  = 1.06720.

[image]

As the conversation with @Glenn reveals, there is more than one answer to this problem. If you prefer the other solution, constrain the search space for y:

```
g[x_] := NMinimize[{Abs[1/Log[y] - (y - x)], y > 1}, y][[2, 1, 2]] //Quiet
Plot[x + g[x]^2, {x, 1, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: A nice trick! However, FindRoot[1/Log[y] == y - 1, {y, 2}] tells me {y -> 2.23998}.

Comment: @Glenn -- So there's more than one answer! Note that FindRoot[1/Log[y] == y - 1, {y, 0.5}] gives 0.2592!

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to check the constraint has two solutions! Now I see that your solution is also correct. Sorry!